# Manipulating entries from multiple columns from different tables in a single string - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to pull entries from two tables, one column from table 'Faculty' and two columns from  'Qualified'. I'm supposed to put them in a single query and manipulate them when displayed.

Example of the tables I'm working with:

```
 Table Qualified

 FacultyID| CourseID  |DateQualified
 ------------------------------------
 2143     | ISM 3112  | 01-SEP-88
 2143     | ISM 3113  | 01-SEP-88
 3467     | ISM 4212  | 01-SEP-95
 3467     | ISM 4930  | 01-SEP-96
 4756     | ISM 3113  | 01-SEP-91
 4756     | ISM 3112  | 01-JAN-91


Table: Faculty

FacultyID | FacultyName
--------------------
2143      | Birkin
3467      | Berndt
4756      | Collins
```

I'm supposed to take the values from FacultyName, CourseID, and DateQualified to make a query that looks like this:

```
BIRKIN:: ISM3112 -Sep 1st, '88
```

So, the name is now upper, the '-' in the course name is gone, and the year is now in 'YY format. I'm unsure on how to bring them all into one string and manipulate them. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.FacultyName || ':: ' || replace(s.CourseID,' ','') || '-' ||
       substr(to_char(s.DateQualified,'MONTH'),0,3) || ' ' || to_char(s.DateQualified,'DD')
       || ', `' || to_char(s.DateQualified,'YY') 
FROM Qualified s 
INNER JOIN Faculty t
ON(s.FacultyID = t.FacultyID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a way to remove the space from CourseID and change the date from being displayed as 01-JAN-91 to -Jan 1st, '91?

Comment: @RyanRoss Thats the best I can do .. no more space, and will be -Jan 1, 91

Comment: That is not a way that I'm aware of that the day can be represented as 1st,2nd ETC . is this working for you?